# Disable Azure AD Sync

Tags: active-directory, azure

I deleted my Active Directory home lab and forgot to disable Azure Active Directory Synchronization on teh server before I deleted it. I keep getting emails about an unhealthy synchronization, but I can't figure out how to disable the functionality in the Azure portal. How do I disable Azure AD Sync after my on-premise AD server was destroyed?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/turn-off-directory-synchronization

Comment: Can I run that from any machine?

Comment: Yes, form any machine that has the required components, as specified in the article.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/928483/how-to-stop-syncing-windows-server-with-azure-active-directory